# I change my requests file in my laptop, how can I replace it?

Tags: python-requests

I encountered an issue with my 'requests' import; it was showing an error when running the program. Consequently, I modified the 'requests' file on my computer. I believe I may have made things worse rather than better. If someone is willing to help, I would appreciate it.

Here is the error message I'm receiving.

cd /Users/josephamblard/Desktop ; /usr/bin/env /usr/bin/python3 /Users/josephamblard/.

vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.22.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher 65487 -- /Users/josephambl

ard/Desktop/test.py

/Users/josephamblard/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/urllib3/**init**.py:34: NotOpenSSLWarning: urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with 'LibreSSL 2.8.3'. See: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/3020

warnings.warn(

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/josephamblard/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/requests/compat.py", line 11, in

```
import chardet
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chardet'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/josephamblard/Desktop/test.py", line 1, in

```
import requests
```

File "/Users/josephamblard/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/requests/**init**.py", line 45, in

```
from .exceptions import RequestsDependencyWarning
```

File "/Users/josephamblard/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/requests/exceptions.py", line 9, in

```
from .compat import JSONDecodeError as CompatJSONDecodeError
```

File "/Users/josephamblard/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/requests/compat.py", line 13, in

```
import charset_normalizer as chardet
```

File "/Users/josephamblard/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/charset_normalizer/**init**.py", line 24, in

```
from .api import from_bytes, from_fp, from_path, is_binary
```

File "/Users/josephamblard/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/charset_normalizer/api.py", line 5, in

```
from .cd import (
```

File "/Users/josephamblard/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/charset_normalizer/cd.py", line 14, in

```
from .md import is_suspiciously_successive_range
```

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/josephamblard/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/charset_normalizer/md.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/josephamblard/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/charset_normalizer/md.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/josephamblard/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/charset_normalizer/md.cpython-39-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Users/josephamblard/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/charset_normalizer/md.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))

Thank you for your help.